# Error in your SQL syntax while Inserting to table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am receiving an error

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'all (Abonent,
>   Opponent, Type, Data, Duration, idBase, IMEI, Direction) value' at
>   line 1

while trying to run this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
if ($row[2]=='Передача данных'){$type = 'Интернет';}else {$type = NULL;}
$date = date_create_from_format ( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', $row[3]);
$da=  date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$mysql = "INSERT INTO all (Abonent, Opponent, Type, Data, Duration, idBase,         IMEI, Direction) 
  values ('$row[0]', '$row[1]','$type', '$da', '$row[4]', '$row[5]',     '$row[6]', '$row[7]')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql);
  }
```

I've checked similar questions here: none of the attribute names are seem to be keywords, neither is in the use of backticks. Types of my table attributes:

```
Abonent bigint(12)  (key)
Opponent    bigint(12)  
Type    text    
Data    datetime    
Duration    bigint(20)  
idBase  bigint(10)  (key)   
IMEI    bigint(16)      
Direction   varchar(15)
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statments to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Check for Errors after executing SQL Statements (`mysqli_error($conn)`)

Comment: The query reads `INSERT INTO all ...` and MySQL doesn't understand who is `all`. Does the `all` table exists?

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statements? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: try removing all key word after insert into

Comment: @Jens the error is posted in the question. The SQL statement doesn't execute because of the syntax error in the query.

Comment: try like this INSERT INTO 'all' ............

Comment: @axiac I see. But it should checked in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`All` is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Do not use it as table name or escape it using backticks.